# Does a bounded sequence having a single limit point always have a limit?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Every bounded sequence has at least one limit point. (Bolzano Weierstrass Theorem)
If such a sequence has a unique limit point, need that point be the limit of the sequence?

Comment: It is true if $(a_n)$ is Cauchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is true and you will find the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1552411/prove-x-n-converges-iff-x-n-is-bounded-and-has-at-most-one-limit-point) if, and only if, the space is compact.

If not, take for instance $X=(0,1)$, then the sequence $x_n=1/2$ is $n$ is even and $x_n=1/n$ if $n$ is odd as a unique limit point on $X$ but it does not converges.